# SQL Server Integration Services Projects not available in Visual Studio Extensions

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to install SQL Server Integration Services Projects in Visual Studio. I am doing the following:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not available in Visual Studio 2022, but I found it in Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

[image]

Visual Studio 2022 is not supported:

[image]

For Visual Studio 2017, I had to go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-ver16 and download it from the link below:

SSDT for VS 2017 (standalone installer)
[Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.10)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2192400)

Then I just installed it:

[image]

Comment: When I search (using VS 2019 version 16.11.19) I don't see it in the marketplace and if I go to it in my Roaming list it won't allow me to download. Manually downloading and running the installer from the VS website shows my 2019 and 2022 instances but both say that it can't be installed for those instances.

Comment: I manually downloaded version 2017 but I don't remember getting an error telling me that it can't be installed.

Comment: For 2017 that might be the case. For 2019 on the page where it asks which instances you want it installed on it listed 2022 and 2019, but both were disabled with a message saying that it wasn't valid for those two instances.

Comment: Maybe it is only compatible with version 2017 with the "Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.10)" that I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, but you also showed a screenshot with the VS Marketplace for 2019. I'm saying that it was not available there for me. I don't know why it is available for you and not for me, so if someone else has insight into that then it would be very helpful.

Comment: @TomH In my question see how in the screenshot it is not available. I had the same issue. I don't know why. When it is available in the screenshot of my answer, if I remember correctly, it was only when I used Visual Studio 2019, but I wanted to use Visual Studio 2017. So I did the manual install.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add the extension to VS 2022. Curious that the version looks older. [image]